# Using skimage view_as_windows with step of (w,h)

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm using skimage `view_as_windows` to get patches of a 3d image (RGB) of shape (100,150,3).

My windows shape is (20,25,3) and my step (stride) is (9,12). I need to input the step variable as a tuple with len as the len of shape of the image (meaning tuple of length 3). When running the function with `step = (9,12,3)` or `step = (9,12,1)` the output shape is not as expected, too few windows are created. How should I use the function with non-square step? Didn't find an example in the docs for this scenario.

code example:

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img[:,:,:3], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # img shape (1376, 2124, 3)
tile = (250, 600, 3) # shape of window
stride = (150, 500)
tiles = view_as_windows(img, tile, (stride[0], stride[1], 3))
```

tiles variable shape was expected not as expected

Comment: [mre] required.

Comment: added an example. I found a bug in my code so closing the thread. now everything works.